# How can I write find and exec command in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script that does

`find /tmp/test/* -name "*.json" -exec python /python/path {} \;`

it looks for all the JSON files in specific directories and executes the OTHER python script that I have..

How can I do this python scripting?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Take a look at `os.listdir` or `glob`

Comment: maybe look into the os module (`os.listdir('/tmp/test')`) or the glob module (`glob.glob('/tmp/test/*.json')`). then a for loop should do it.

Comment: glob i think is what you want ... and os.system

Comment: @RafiK how can I write glob function in for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob,subprocess
for json_file in glob.glob("/home/tmp/*.json"):
    subprocess.Popen(["python","/path/to/my.py",json_file],env=os.environ).communicate()
```

Comment: lets say /home/tmp is DIR1 and /test/ is dirname. There are subdirectories inside of /test/ and in that subdirectories there are json files.. so i tried glob.glob(DIR1+dirname+'/*/*.json') it does not work.. it takes * as the name not as all the names.. how can I fix this? @Joran Beasley

Comment: using `/home/temp/test/*/*.json` it should give you all the json files in any immediate subdirectory (ex `/home/temp/test/a/a.json, /home/temp/test/b/a.json, ...`

Comment: i meant without hard coding the path.. how can i do this using variable? i tried above statement as i mentioned.. but it is not working @Joran

Comment: use `os.path.join(DIR1, dirname, '*/*.json')`. it can save some headaches concerning path separators `//`, `/`, `\`, ...

Comment: @RafiK or just always use "/" as your seperators ...  Ive had `os.path.join` screw up paths for me before

Comment: @PETER ... lets leave that as a learning step for you .... its not hard i promise ... maybe print your (variable) path and see what might be wrong with it ... then try and make it right ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ok, good to know, thanks! Do you have an example of it failing by chance? As a side note: the purpose of making it platform independent is not achieved here due to the last argument containing a hard coded `/`. So yeah, just concat the strings, thats easier..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, if you are trying to execute a shell command from a python script, you can use os.system() :

```
import os
os.system('ls -l')
```

[complete documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python instead of find, start with [os.walk](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/) ([official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.walk)) to get the files. Once you have them (or as you them), act on them however you like.

From that page:

```
import os

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
        # act on the file
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to adjust your other python file `/python/path/script.py`, such that you only need this one file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import glob
import os

#
# parse the command line arguemnts
#
for i, n in enumerate(sys.argv):
    # Debug output
    print "arg nr %02i: %s" % (i, n)

    # Store the args in variables
    # (0 is the filename of the script itself)
    if i==1:
        path = sys.argv[1] # the 1st arg is the path like "/tmp/test"
    if i==2:
        pattern = sys.argv[2] # a pattern to match for, like "'*.json'"

#
# merge path and pattern
# os.path makes it win / linux compatible ( / vs \ ...) and other stuff
#
fqps = os.path.join(path, pattern)

#
# Do something with your files
#
for filename in glob.glob(fqps):
    print filename

    # Do your stuff here with one file        
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:  # 'r'= only ready from file ('w' = write)
        lines = f.readlines()
    # at this point, the file is closed again!
    for line in lines:
        print line
        # and so on ...
```

Then you can use the one script like this
`/python/path/script.py /tmp/test/ '*.json'`. (Without needing to write `python` in front, thanks to the very first line, called shebang. But you need to make it executable once, using `chmod +x /python/path/script.py`)

Of course you can omit the 2nd arg and assign a default value to pattern, or only use one arg in the first place. I did it this way to demonstrate `os.path.join()` and quoting of arguments that should not be extended by bash (compare the effect of using `'*.json'` and `*.json` on the printed list of arguments at the start)

[Here](http://www.diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/command_line_arguments.html) are some information about better / more sophisticated ways of handling command line arguments.

And, as a bonus, [using a main() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) is advisable as well, to keep overview if your script gets larger or is being used by other python scripts.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Why? could you please help me? I don't see the error? Of course, there are more elegant / compact ways to do it, but I hoped this way would show better whats going on and would allow more easily to add checks to make sure the arguments are valid, if one wants to extend from this example later on.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

```
find /tmp/test/* -name "*.json" -exec sh -c "python /python/path {}" \;
```